# How do animals adapt to a partially or fully deaf individual of their group?

Tags: hearing, adaptation

In eusocial animals for which hearing is important to communicate between individuals, is there any species apart humans for which there are some evidence that the group adapts their acoustic communication to a fully or partially deaf individual of the group?

For instance, by systematically vocalizing louder/closer to a partially deaf individual, or switching the communication modality (e.g. acoustics to touching) for a fully deaf individual, or by showing more support to them when an alarm call is raised, etc.

I have not found any information after a quick search on the web and Google Scholar.

Comment: Did you search for possible literature? If so it would be good to give some indication of that. Also, I think "eurosocial" should be "eusocial", right?

Comment: Thanks @DanStowell, done!